# Make Aptana studio 3 use existing Rails project not import

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana3

Im giving Aptana Studio 3 a try. Well hoping to.

I would like to open an existing Rails project but it asks me to import it. I dont want to make a copy I just want to use the same source files.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to Project Explorer (tab in right side of aptana window - if you got default layout) -> find directory with your project -> right click on it -> "Promote to project"

Answer (score 1):

Frankly Aptana 3 is not organized to have the source files in the same directory.  Basically it forces you to have the source files in two separate directories (source editing, deployed) and regardless of what you want it does particularly care.

Now if I'm wrong on this and someone can do a simple step by step on how to do this then I'm all ears.  Personally I just want to have the source in my local web folder and then just edit it.  I do not have any interest in deploying it to another server.  Nor in using github or any other service.  I just want to edit the stupid files locally and then test the site locally.  And I am unwilling to waste any more time on this ide trying to get it to work.